session of editor to restore
I have multiple terminals with vi editor session. If i have  5 windows, there will be 5 cscope with vi file. However, when boot to windows, I need to close it and  restore it back. applications like tmux will not help across reboot is my impression. How can I save sessions and restore back after ubuntu starts? I am fine to start terminals though vi file and line numbers should restore back like tmux.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

There's a plugin for tmux called Tmux Resurrect.
It restores your tmux session after a reboot, and additionally it can also restore vim sessions. So this might be what you're looking for.
